# Portal Redirect in Microsoft Dynamics Portals

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, powerapps, dynamics-crm-portals

User
I want to redirect to the "Sign in" page "onclick" of website .. I don't want to redirect to the "home" page in the d365 portals.

The problem here is the "Home" is a webpage, but when it comes to the "Sign in" it is a content snippet!

I tried to configure the things in the "Portal management" but I'm unable to figure it out.